# How can i remove odd index element from the list?

Tags: python, list

### It show list index out of range. i need to remove all odd index element but it's not working and showing list index out of range

```
list1 = [12,33,45,66,75,33,4,56,66,67,1,2]
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            x=i
            if(i%2!=0):
                #print(list1[x])
                list1.remove(list1[x])
            else:
                continue
        print(list1)
```

Comment: your list is getting smaller with each element you remove, after a while your index gets out of range

Comment: in `for` loop say `for i in range(len(list_)):` and then with the execution of every loop you are changing length of `list_`  then also `i` will vary from `0<=i<len(list_)`
I can see people have answered your question you need to accept answer. 
[How to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

Just do this, it should work

```
list1 = [12,33,45,66,75,33,4,56,66,67,1,2]
list1=list1[::2]
print(list1)`
```

output:-
`[12, 45, 75, 4, 66, 1]`

Comment: This is a very concise solution, but you should mention that the Python sequence slicing works like `list1[start:end:step]`, and you have omitted the `start` and `end` parameters (to process the whole list, and just specified the `step` parameter as `2` in order to get all the even-indexed list values.

Comment: Thanks for tip.I'll keep in mind the explanation in my future contribution to the site.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
del list1[1::2]
```

It's a direct translation from *"remove all odd index element"* to Python code.

**Benchmark** along with the upvoted solutions for a list with a million elements:

```
11.8 ms  11.9 ms  12.0 ms  list1 = list1[::2]
90.1 ms  90.6 ms  91.1 ms  list1 = [i for indexValue, i in enumerate(list1) if indexValue % 2 == 0]
 8.0 ms   8.2 ms   8.2 ms  del list1[1::2]
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDdaoQwEIXv8xTnZjERWTZrKUXwNXojUiyObUCTEEfYPr1NdNd2c5Of@WbOyfE//O1s@ebDug7BTWAzkWGYybvACOSpYyFm4sWjRjaamXU8pF2Gzn6R1Jc8f1Uqi5QbFzbOzhFoBOJ64nVTVdc2K54rjcHgAozt6fbejQsVMPEGsstEoWOSG6lghn8QTriirnE55vU03lX0XaYVIk3@SNN2q6WqNjg9P8ym6mF8L6eVckj/mGMM1Ms9CPkAC2yJFIgmPynUWqmmKtuj2wdjWeYyO72c9YBpRhYdS0YOTaXaDHBS3mRUcThQ4q9dresv)):

```
from timeit import repeat

setup = 'list1 = list(range(10**6))'

solutions = [
    'list1 = list1[::2]',
    'list1 = [i for indexValue, i in enumerate(list1) if indexValue % 2 == 0]',
    'del list1[1::2]',
]

for _ in range(3):
    for solution in solutions:
        times = sorted(repeat(solution, setup, number=1))[:3]
        print(*('%4.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3) for t in times), solution)
    print()
```

Comment: @PratyushArora No, this deletes all **odd**-indexed elements. Yes, `list[0]` is the **first** element, but its **index** is **0**, which is **even**. Besides, your own solution gets the same result, so it's not clear how you're confused. Did you overlook that I'm using `del`?

Comment: Ahh im real sorry i just glanced at the slicing not the del

Answer (score 1):

### Issue:

Your code isn't working for the given snippet because every time you remove an element from `list1`, an index from the same gets eliminated.

### Solution:

To overcome this issue using the iterative method, you need to append the even elements to another list, or as [Pratyush Arora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16917938/pratyush-arora) stated, any could work.

If you're using the iterative method, this could be helpful:

### Code:

```py
list1 = [12,33,45,66,75,33,4,56,66,67,1,2]

# Using list comprehension
evenIndexList = [i for indexValue, i in enumerate(list1) if indexValue % 2 == 0]
print(evenIndexList)

# Standard approach
newList = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
         newList.append(list1[i])
print(newList)
```

Comment: I like the list comprehension and enumerate method. Very pythonic and almost certainly faster than the list append traditional/basic method.

Comment: @SteveGoossens Nah, pretty complicated and slow. Using a lot of Python code doesn't necessarily mean pythonic :-P

Comment: @SteveGoossens Added a benchmark to my answer now.

Comment: nice one for adding the timings... I guess enumerate is the slow part and the modulus evaluation probably isn't the fastest way to determine odd/even?

Comment: @SteveGoossens Well, it's a combination of those two things and of doing it in Python rather than making C code do it. And using modulus might be the fastest way to determine odd/even in Python, but it's still faster to not determine it at all and just go in steps of 2 :-). Although `if not indexValue % 2` would be faster than `if indexValue % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following :

```
list1 = [12,33,45,66,75,33,4,56,66,67,1,2]
list1 = [list1[i] for i in range(0,len(list1),2)]
print(list1)
```

output :

```
[12, 45, 75, 4, 66, 1]
```

Comment: What's the output of that, and does it look correct to you?

Comment: Totally correct . What do you think ?

Comment: Why did you delete the 66 between 4 and 1? It's at an even index.

Comment: because he said that he wants to delete the odd index element :" i need to remove all odd index element".Right ?

Comment: But it's an *even* index element.

Comment: The index of 66 is 3 .

Comment: As I said I'm talking about the 66 *between 4 and 1*. Its index is 8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237323/discussion-between-ayyoub-essadeq-and-dont-talk-just-code).

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to use your way, you can use it:

```
list1 = [12,33,45,66,75,33,4,56,66,67,1,2]
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
            if(i%2!=1):
                list2.append(list1[i])
print(list2)
```

list2 contains all even numbers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

```
from copy import deepcopy

list1 = [12,33,45,66,75,33,4,56,66,67,1,2]
list2 = deepcopy(list1)
for i in range(len(list2)):
    if(i%2!=0):
        #print(list1[x])
        list1.remove(list2[i])
    else:
        continue
print(list1)
```

The above issue occurs when we try to remove an element from a list and the same time we are iterating through the same list.
To overcome this issue we can create a copy of the list using `deepcopy` and then iterate through `list2`. For the removal of the elements use the `list1`.

Output

```
[12, 45, 75, 4, 66, 1]
```

Comment: `list1.copy` to avoid `deepcopy`, as it's a shallow list anyway

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: `list2 = list1.copy()` creates a shallow copy, which works out in this case as it's not a nested list. This can be used to avoid the need for `deepcopy` which is rather slow (it might also be helpful to time these different methods to see how they differ)

Comment: also, `range(len(list2))` can be replaced with `enumerate(list2)` - i noticed this will be more useful since you're also accessing each element in `list2`, and with `enumerate` you also get a loop variable for the current element.

Comment: This is costly, as `remove` is an O(n) operation, making this answer O(n^2)